# Is there is any way to find out from where an image is loaded to browser. From server / browser cache/ proxy cache etc

Tags: html, image, caching

Is there is any way to find out from where an image is loaded to browser. From server / browser cache or proxy cache etc. I am using asp.net MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take on this:

1) **Server**: Default; the request can be seen on the Fiddler.

2) **Browse cache**: No request is sent so Fiddler will not show a request to the server. Also if the resource is changed on the server, it is not updated on the client.

3) **Proxy/Cache server**: It is tricky and not always reliable. It looks like the server but you will most likely see X-cache or similar cache related and sometimes non-standard headers, depending on the proxy or the cache server used.